# Abrir o app do MEGA quando um link do site for clicado na webview

Tags: java, android, webview, intent

Estou desenvolvendo um app para meu site e quero que quando um determinado usuário clicar no link de download, que neste caso é no mega, seja aberto o APLICATIVO do mega automaticamente, assim como é feito em navegadores chrome e todos os outros.
Lembrando que tem que ser funcional para quaisquer link do MEGA, pois são vários e eles mudam. Então tem que equivaler a todos.
Estou iniciando na programação, e já pesquisei bastante, só que não encontrei o que realmente queria.
Aqui segue minha Activity principal:

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.res.Configuration;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager;
import android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarDrawerToggle;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.view.KeyEvent;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.webkit.WebChromeClient;
import android.webkit.WebView;
import android.webkit.WebViewClient;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.ProgressBar;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

    private DrawerLayout mDrawerLayout;
    private ListView mDrawerList;
    String[] titles = {"Nigeria", "Ghana", "Senegal", "Togo"};
    private CharSequence mTitle;
    private CharSequence mDrawerTitle;
    private ActionBarDrawerToggle mDrawerToggle;
    private Toolbar topToolBar;
    private WebView webView;
    Activity activity = this;
    private ProgressBar progress;
    private WebView webview;
    private static final String TAG = "Main";
    private View view;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        webView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.website);
        webView.getSettings().setLoadWithOverviewMode(true);
        webView.getSettings().setUseWideViewPort(true);

        webView.getSettings().setSupportZoom(true);
        webView.getSettings().setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
        webView.getSettings().setDisplayZoomControls(false);

        webView.setScrollBarStyle(WebView.SCROLLBARS_OUTSIDE_OVERLAY);
        webView.setScrollbarFadingEnabled(false);
        webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        webView.loadUrl("http://meusite");

        webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
            @Override
            public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
                webView.loadUrl(url);
                return false;
            }
        });

        progress = (ProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.progressBar);
        progress.setMax(100);

        mTitle = mDrawerTitle = getTitle();

        topToolBar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(topToolBar);

        mDrawerLayout = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        mDrawerList = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.left_drawer);

        mDrawerToggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(MainActivity.this, mDrawerLayout, R.string.drawer_open, R.string.drawer_close) {

            /** Called when a drawer has settled in a completely closed state. */
            public void onDrawerClosed(View view) {
                super.onDrawerClosed(view);
                getSupportActionBar().setTitle(mTitle);
                invalidateOptionsMenu(); // creates call to onPrepareOptionsMenu()
            }

            /** Called when a drawer has settled in a completely open state. */
            public void onDrawerOpened(View drawerView) {
                super.onDrawerOpened(drawerView);
                getSupportActionBar().setTitle(mDrawerTitle);
                invalidateOptionsMenu(); // creates call to onPrepareOptionsMenu()
            }
        };

        // Set the drawer toggle as the DrawerListener
        mDrawerLayout.setDrawerListener(mDrawerToggle);
        mDrawerToggle.setDrawerIndicatorEnabled(true);

        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
        getSupportActionBar().setHomeButtonEnabled(true);

        mDrawerList.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                // make Toast when click
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Position " + position, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                selectItemFragment(position);
            }
        });
    }

    private void selectItemFragment(int position) {

        Fragment fragment = null;
        FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
        switch (position) {
            default:
            case 0:
                fragment = new DefaultFragment();
                break;
            case 1:
                fragment = new DefaultFragment();
                break;
            case 2:
                fragment = new DefaultFragment();
                break;
            case 3:
                fragment=new DefaultFragment();
                break;
        }
        fragmentManager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.main_fragment_container, fragment).commit();

        mDrawerList.setItemChecked(position, true);
        setTitle(titles[position]);
        mDrawerLayout.closeDrawer(mDrawerList);
    }

    @Override
    public void setTitle(CharSequence title) {
        mTitle = title;
        getSupportActionBar().setTitle(mTitle);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onPostCreate(savedInstanceState);
        // Sync the toggle state after onRestoreInstanceState has occurred.
        mDrawerToggle.syncState();
    }

    @Override
    public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
        super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
        mDrawerToggle.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onPrepareOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // If the nav drawer is open, hide action items related to the content view
        boolean drawerOpen = mDrawerLayout.isDrawerOpen(mDrawerList);
        return super.onPrepareOptionsMenu(menu);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }
        if (mDrawerToggle.onOptionsItemSelected(item)) {
            return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);

    }

    private class MyWebViewClient extends WebChromeClient {
        @Override
        public void onProgressChanged(WebView view, int newProgress) {
            MainActivity.this.setValue(newProgress);
            super.onProgressChanged(view, newProgress);
        }
    }
    public void setValue(int progress) {
        this.progress.setProgress(progress);

}

    @Override
    public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
        if (event.getAction() == KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
            switch (keyCode) {
                case KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK:
                    if (webView.canGoBack()) {
                        webView.goBack();
                    } else {
                        finish();
                    }
                    return true;
            }

        }
        return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pode usar um simples metodo `onclick` pra quando clicarem no link, execultar um serviço `intent` que abre a `acvitivy` padrao do app MEGA apenas informando ao objeto `intent` o nome da package do mega!

```
link_text = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.link);
link_text.setOnClickListener(new View.OnclickListiner() {
     @override
     public void onClick(View arg0) {
          Intent startMega = context.getPackageManager().getLaunchIntentForPackage("nz.mega.android");
          context.startActivity(startMega);
     }
});
```

Contudo, vc pode usar um codigo que checa se o usuario tem o app do MEGA instalado, se nao tiver, um dialogo aparece com duas opções: "Baixar na Google play", e cancelar". Se tiver instalado, o dialogo nao aparece e o `intent` é execultado. Para checar se o app ta instalado veja isto. [Como ver se um determinado app está instalado](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6758841/how-can-i-learn-whether-a-particular-package-exists-on-my-android-device)

Comment: Olá amigo, muito obrigado pela resposta. Eu adicionei esse textview em meu layout para a id:link ficar viável. <TextView android:id="@+id/link" android:onClick="link_text" android:layout_width="match_parent" android: layout_height="wrap_content" /> Mas ainda continua aparecendo este erro: Não foi possível carregar a página da Web no endereço intent://#!e9gjEARR!chvZtFqyer8IOJlZrnfx2t6Zq7bYOTLI63OrWXF0yQw/#Intent;scheme=mega;package=nz.mega.android;endporque: net::ERR_UNKNOWN_URL_SCHEME Você pode me ajudar?

Comment: O proprio erro ja diz... ESQUEMA DE URL DESCONHECIDO, vc tem que olhar de onde ta vindo essa url mal formada, ou por que ta deformada... ate onde sei a url do mega começa com mega.nz/#...

Comment: Olá amigo, então, obrigado novamente por responder. Acontece que sim, a url começa com https://mega.nz/#... Neste caso creio que este tanto de carácter indica a 'id' de um arquivo. Exemplo: https://mega.nz/#!Sw4S1RBQ, este link é da versão desktop, e o que eu citei no erro, é da versão mobile. Mas ambos da o mesmo erro e a url pra download todas começam assim, como essa: https://mega.nz/#!Sw4S1RBQ. Me ajuda, por favor?